# Insert Text into PopUp Field (text input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, email

I am using Wordpress.

There are a lot of posts, each post has a user e-mail address.

I have installed PopUp form. So next to each e-mail there is a button "Email Author".

PopUp form has input fields like:

1. Send to: Here should be Email taken from the post
2. Your Email:
3. Message
4. Send Button

What I need is to take the Email Address and insert it (like real value) into the "Send to:" input field in PopUp when a user clicks the button in the post "Email Author".

How to do it using jQuery and JavaScript?

Here is the code of the post:

```html
<article id="post-3889"
    class="post-3889 post type-post status-publish format-aside hentry category-sex post_format-post-format-aside">
    <div class="aside">
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="http://example.com/2020/04/01/%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80/" rel="bookmark">
                Looking for a girl!
            </a>
        </h1>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <p>I am alone and looking for girls in CA.</p>
            <ul class="wpuf_customs">
                <li class="Age">
                    <label>Age</label>: <span>24</span>
                    <a href="" class="dop sendMessage popmake-se pum-trigger" style="cursor: pointer;">write</a>
                </li>
                <li class="Parameters">
                    <label>Your parameters</label>: <span>190.70.19</span>
                    <a href="" class="dop sendMessage popmake-se pum-trigger" style="cursor: pointer;">text</a>
                </li>
                <li class="Goal">
                    <label>Goal</label>: <span>Chat</span>
                </li>
                <li class="E-mail">
                    <label>E-mail</label>: <span>
                        <a href="mailto:samplemail@gmail.com">samplemail@gmail@gmail.com</a>
                    </span>
                    <a href="" class="dop sendMessage popmake-se pum-trigger" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        Email Author of the Post!
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- .entry-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- .aside -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <div class="cols">
            <a href="http://example.com/2020/04/01/%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80/" title="Permanent link: Looking for a girl!"
                rel="bookmark">5 hours ago</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cols comentz"></div>
        <div class="cols"></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- .entry-meta -->
</article>
```

And here how the PopUp form looks:

```html
<p>
    <label>Send to:<br>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap to-email">
            <input type="email" name="to-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        </span>
    </label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would work if the form is always present in some place of the page.

```
$(".sendMessage").click(function(e){

   console.log($(this));

  e.preventDefault();
    var insertTo = $("input[name='to-email']");

  var email = $(this).parent().find('a[href*="mailto"]').text();
  console.log(email);

  insertTo.val(email);

});
```

Explanation:

1. Add a click listener for all links with class *sendMessage*
2. Get some input in the page with attribute *name='to-email'*
3. Get the email from the **closest** link that href attribute contains *"mailto"*... this step is important because you will have many posts in the page, and you need to pick the right one to fill into from input.
4. Just insert the email into the input.

Hope that puts you in the right direction.

Check out this jsfiffle to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/du03hek7/